# Method on class [] was used outside of a Grails application controller

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class, grails-2.3

Having below grails config:
Datasource.

```
environments {
development {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
        url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
    }

    datasource_staging_oracle {
        dbCreate = "none"
        url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//myoraclehost:1521/DBNAME"
        driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
        username = "username"
        password = "password"
    }
}
```

Domain class:

```
import org.springframework.integration.Message

class SpringMessage {

    static mapping = {
        datasource 'staging_oracle'
        message type: 'blob', column: 'message_bytes'
        createdDate type: Date, column: 'created_date'
    }
    static constraints = {
    }

    String messageId
    Message<?> message
    Date createdDate
}
```

Inside the controller, fetching the records using:

```
SpringMessage springMessage = SpringMessage.findByMessageId('messsage_id_value')
```

Above line fails with below error:
*Method on class [com.foo.bar.SpringMessage] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.*

How to resolve this? Googling shows grails "test" related posts. But this is not test code. Above findBy method is called from a grails controller.
I am on grails 2.3.3 and unfortunately can not upgrade to latest grails as of now.

**UPDATE**
Controller code:

```
class FooController {
    def index() {
        foo2()
    }
    private def foo2() {
        SpringMessage springMessage = SpringMessage.findByMessageId('my_message_id') //This line blowsup
        if ( springMessage) {
            println springMessage.createdDate
        } else {
            println "not found"
        }
    }
}
```

I access the controller using http://localhost:8080/myapp/foo/index

**UPDATE**
Blob column declaration is incorrect in my original question. Correct version is below:

```
class SpringMessage {

    static mapping = {
        datasource 'staging_oracle'
        message type: 'blob', column: 'message_bytes'
        createdDate type: Date, column: 'created_date'
    }
    static constraints = {
    }

    String messageId
    Blob message
    Date createdDate
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the controller implementation?

Comment: @saw303 Updated the post with controller snippet

Comment: How do you run Grails?

Comment: Its from Intellijj.  Run grails with "run-app" argument.

Comment: Can you try it from the command line and add the complete Stacktrace? run grails run-app from the command line

Comment: Found the solution. Its an ugly typo in datasource configuration.

Comment: please provide the solution in order to answer your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue is because of a typo in DataSource.groovy:
dataSource word should have 'S' in upper case. Yikes. Grails should have warned on this.

```
environments {
  development {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
        url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
    }

    dataSource_staging_oracle {
        dbCreate = "none"
        url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//myoraclehost:1521/DBNAME"
        driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
        username = "username"
        password = "password"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this issue.

In my DataSource.groovy I was specifying the secondary dataSource as `dataSource_mysql` and in my domain class mapping block I had it the same. Turns out within the domain class I needed to reference the datasource as just `mysql` without the `dataSource_`.

Once I made this change I was able to call the domain methods from my controller without this error being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Your domain class `SpringMessage` uses a `org.springframework.integration.Message` as domain property `message`. There error tries to indicate that `org.springframework.integration.Message` is not a Grails domain object and cannot no be mapped against the database.

You need to introduce a domain object holding the relevant data of your `org.springframework.integration.Message` instance. Probably you are trying to store the payload of the Spring Integration Message.

```
class SpringMessage {

  static mapping = {
    datasource 'staging_oracle'
    message type: 'blob', column: 'message_bytes'
    createdDate type: Date, column: 'created_date'
  }
  static constraints = {
  }

  String messageId
  String message // use a String instead of the message instance
  Date createdDate
}
```

and then set the payload to the `SpringMessage`

```
new SpringMessage(
    messageId: 'ID', 
    message: message.payload, 
    createdDate: new Date()
).save()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Still same error when I changed the `message` property type to String